# C# 5.0 async/await feature and Rx - Reactive Extensions

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, c#-5.0, async-await

I am wondering what do the new C# 5.0 asynchronous features mean for Rx - Reactive Extensions? It seems to be not a replacement but they seem to overlap - `Task` and `IObservable`.

Comment: "Async/await" is not a replacement for Rx any more than LINQ was a replacement for SQL. You can use LINQ to talk to a SQL back end; you can use task-based asynchrony with Rx to orchestrate work triggered by streams of events. These technologies should enhance each other, not compete.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Check also: [TPL Dataflow Overview](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=205053) about TDF and Rx:

> Astute readers may notice some similarities between TPL Dataflow and Reactive Extensions (Rx), currently available as a download from the DevLabs prototypes site. Rx is predominantly focused on coordination and composition of event streams with a LINQ-based API, providing a rich set of combinators for manipulating IObservables of data.  In contrast, TPL Dataflow is focused on providing building blocks for message passing and parallelizing CPU- and I/O-intensive applications with high-throughput and low-latency, while also providing developers explicit control over how data is buffered and moves about the system.  As such, Rx and TPL Dataflow, while potentially viewed as similar at a 30,000 foot level, address distinct needs. Even so, TPL Dataflow and Rx provide a better together story.

Answer (score 13):

Jeff writes on the [Rx forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/thread/43b60fc8-7835-4333-a4b9-870b5b32dbce) that Rx will still be used to orchestrate multiple event driven tasks, Rx has release a new version that includes `IAsyncEnumerable` to use the new async features in Rx.

Comment: +1 Also, Bart De Smet talked a little bit about async and Rx (mentioning IAsyncEnumerable) in his PDC talk "LINQ, Take Two" http://player.microsoftpdc.com/